# Fetched data visible in the console but throwing an error when accessing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching the user playlist and whenever the user clicks on the album it redirects to the next page with its ID.

```js
const [playList, setPlatList] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  apiClient.get("me/playlists").then(function (res) {
    setPlatList(res.data.items);
  });
}, []);
const navigate = useNavigate();

// on click event
const playPlayList = (id) => {
  navigate("/player", { state: { id: id } });
};
```

After that, I am getting its id from the location state and call another api for its tracks. In response, I'm getting data and storing it inside `currentTrack` with no problem.

Here is the code for that part:

```
const location = useLocation();
const [tracks, setTracks] = useState([]);
const [currentTrack, setCurrentTack] = useState({});
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
  if (location.state) {
    // cheking state is passed or not
    apiClient.get("playlists/" + location.state?.id + "/tracks").then((response) => {
      setTracks(response.data.items);
      setCurrentTack(response.data.items[0].track);
    });
  }
  console.log(currentTrack);
}, [location.state]); // whenever location chages it re-run
return (
  <div className="screenContainer flex">
    <div className="leftPLayer"></div>
    <div className="rightPlayer">
      <SongCard album={currentTrack.album} />
      <Queue />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

When I log `album` in the `component` it gives me data but when I try to log `album.image` it gives me undefined.

Here is the response from API:

```
"href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/1kUSt70v9jYaJkBeIM6GI4/tracks?offset=0&limit=100",
    "items": [
        {
            "added_at": "2022-05-28T04:30:44Z",
            "added_by": {
                
            },
            
            "track": {
                "album": {
                    "album_group": "single",
                    "album_type": "single",
                    "artists": [
                        {
                            "external_urls": {
                                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/7FmygnepJt3fhiZQDmoC0P"
                            },
                    
                        },
                        {
                            "external_urls": {
                                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/3TwDjxq0xKO564mxocDOhJ"
                            },
                          
                        }

  "external_urls": {
                        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/album/24h6eRROc28kehqHPdb0kf"
                    },
                    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/24h6eRROc28kehqHPdb0kf",
                    "id": "24h6eRROc28kehqHPdb0kf",
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "height": 640,
                            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27321c0833c690bcca5d918e18e",
                            "width": 640
                        },
                        {
                            "height": 300,
                            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0221c0833c690bcca5d918e18e",
                            "width": 300
                        },
                        {
                            "height": 64,
                            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000485121c0833c690bcca5d918e18e",
                            "width": 64
                        }
                    ],
```

I removed some unnecessary things to make it smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `useEffect`'s callback runs after the JSX is rendered, on mount, `currentTrack.album` equals `undefined` because `currentTrack` equals `{}`, that initial value given to `useState`. Therefore `album` in `SongCard` is `undefined`, causing the error.

You could change your state declaration of `currentTrack` to this:

```js
const [currentTrack, setCurrentTack] = useState(null);
```

And show some loader while fetching the data:

```js
if (currentTrack === null) {
  return <p>Loading...</p>;
}

return <div>Render Acutal Data</div>
```